# calculate the amount of money at the end of nth day remaining

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a, b and n where a dollar is the money gained everyday, b is the cost of food to be purchased and, n is the number of days.

Each day "a" money is credited to your account and you would like to buy as many food with the available money as you can where each unit of food cost b.
If you already have food then you wont purchase food that day.you repeat this task for n days and want to calculate the amount of money left at the end of n day.

The brute force solution is to to simulate the task but this will not work as the number of days is very high like 10**9.

The other approach I though of it to

1. If a==b then answer is 0
2. If b>a then answer is (a*n)%b

I am having trouble to figure out the answer for the case when a < b.

Below is an example

> a=5, b=3, n=3
>
> day 1: 5 dollar we can purchase at most 1 food 2 dollar remains
>
> day 2: 2(prev day)+5 dollar we can purchase at most 2 food 1 dollar
>   remains
>
> day 3: 1(prev day)+5 dollar we wont make any purchase as we already
>   have 1 food(from prev day)
>
> 6 dollar remains at the end of day 3

Comment: what's the limit??

Comment: do you mean to say that you are having trouble with `a>b` and not `a<b` since you've already answered the case `a<b`?

Comment: I think, the answer is (n * a) - (n * b)

Comment: @svs yes i am having trouble with a>b and not a<b

Comment: Since you are not buying any extra food, the answer is simply, `n * (a - b)`

Comment: @vish4071 but we *are* buying extra food. From the problem statement: " you would like to buy as many food with the available money as you can". From the example, look at day 2. We buy **2** food.

Comment: @AbuHanifa doesn't match the example shown if `n = 2` (same as the example shown but we stop after two days)

Comment: @PrashantBhanarkar First you say `you would like to buy as many food with the available money as you can` and then `If you already have food then you wont purchase food that day`. I find those two statements contradicting. Could you explain?

Comment: @svs there's no contradiction, once we realise the implicit idea that we eat 1 food per day (at the end of the day, it looks like). Thus, on day 2 we have 0 food so we buy as much as we can; but on day 3 we have one food (carried over from day 2), so we do not buy any food. On each day, we buy either zero food (because we already have food) OR as much as we can afford.

Comment: So, if no of days were 4, in this example, we wud have $11 on 4th day, (6+5), so we buy 3 foods, and are left with $2...is it so?

Comment: @vish4071 yes you are correct the answer must be 2.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaking but the number of days you buy each time will grow exponentially. If you have money for x food today next time you will have `x*(a/b)`, and next-next time you will have `x*(a/b)*(a/b)` and so on.

So you should be able to brute-force it if you exploit the the exponential growth.

If today you have 0 food and x money, then you can buy x/b food, so you can jump x/b days (when you have 0 food again) and you will have (x%b) + (x/b)*a money next time. Since you follow the exponential growth your complexity will be O(logN). If it's not clear take `a=2, b=1` and see that you get to large amounts fairly quickly and you can skip lots of days easily.

One thing to note is the exponentials can be slow to start. If a and b are very close together (`a=1000000 b=999999`) than a/b will be very close to 1. Still logN but you spend too much time in the slow period. In practice it means that you will do lots of iterations where you only skip one or two days. You can also cut this short by noting how much money you make per cycle (between two days when you have to buy food, in my example it would be 1) and calculating how many cycles it will take until you can buy 1 unit more food (you need to take the reminder of what is left after the cycle add it to what money you have now and divide it by the cost of food). Once you know this you can skip all the cycles until you can buy more food.